# Regex to replace url in a text?

Tags: regex, url

Currently using this :

```
MatchCollection urlRegExp = Regex.Matches(text, @"https?://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9/;&=:_$+!*'()|~\[\]#%.\\-]+");
```

to replace urls in a text but it doesn't get every urls, and it seems like i cannot find a good regex for this.. anyone can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: which platform are you using?

Comment: @PM77-1: He/She doesn't try to check if an url is valid or not, but only to find urls in a text, that are two totally different tasks.

Comment: @PM u r rite, this is the same task I believe. What is the difference? If a sub string matches an url then the job is half done. Just need to substitute the replace character.

Answer (score 1):

If you need find urls in a text, you don't need to fit the RFC (whatever the number) it's totally useless (and it's nearly impossible with a pattern that follows the standard, it will be too slow, too complex).

All urls in the text should be considered valid *(and / or must be validated or not before being inserted in the text by the people who produce this text. In other words, it is not your job!)*.

So, you must find an other approach. To do this, you must ask the right question: how to distinguish a URL from the text?

Let's list the common criteria

- a URL may begin with the protocol: http, https, ftp, sftp, ftps, gopher, ...
- a URL may begin with `www.`
- a URL does not contain whitespace characters
- a URL begins always with a word boundary
- a URL may ends before a whitespace character, the end of the string, a punctuation character except the question mark *(that can be present even if there are no GET parameters)*

With these requirements, you can build easily a naive pattern for the http protocol:

```
\b(https?://|www\.)\S+(?=\s|[^\P{P}?]|\z)
```

Note that once you obtain a result, you are free to check the validity of the url with a build-in function *(which generally doesn't handle all the cases however, but now you know why:)*.

Comment: Yea but will it work with urls that i am not aware of like if the url is something like that : testone123.me
or something similar..

Comment: @user3352374: Probably, but there is no way to know if "testone123.me" is a domain name (and by extension an url) or a simple text element. If you build for example a pattern to detect that: `\b\w+\.\w+`, all substrings that looks like this would be matched, and you will obtain false positive results. (imagine someone that forgets a space after a dot: `Bob has got a cat.me, I have a dog.`

Comment: Yea, but would your code you just gave me detect a facebook url or anything like that? what about test123.me/fsifi8e3393 ? :O

Comment: @user3352374: In its current state, obviously not. Remember that my approach is voluntary naive and will only detect substrings that begins with `http://` or `www` *(in other words, this will detect the intention to write an URL, nothing more)*. If you want to detect URLs without `http://` or `www` but that have well-known domains, it's also possible to include them in the pattern with an alternation : `\b(https?://|www\.|domain1\.com|domain2\.com)\S*(?=\s|[^\P{P}?]|\z)`. But looking for all possible urls hidden in a text by a syntax analysis is really (in my opinion) a waste of time.

Comment: In particular, I am thinking about forums that try to forbid users to  write urls in a post in the 90s. The pattern or string search to detect URLs was based on the `http://` substring. Immediatly after, people that want to write an url in a post wrote: `h**p://` to avoid the detection.